# What does "that" refers to in this piece of dialogue?

Tags: meaning

It's from the movie "You can count on me".

Ron, who is a church minister, asks Terry if Terry thinks that his life is important. Terry says yes and elaborates:

*Terry*: I'd like to think that my life is important... Or that it's connected to something important...

*Ron*: Well, isn't there any way for you to believe that without calling it God, or religion, or whatever term it is you object to?

*Terry*: **Yes. I believe that**.

I don't get what Terry is saying. He "believes that". What? Does he believe that his life is important even without God or religion? Or to the contrary, is he saying that he actually believes in God? I find the phrasing confusing.

Comment: "I'd like to think that my life is important, or that it's connected to something important....without calling it God, or religion..."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not an appropriate use of ELU. We don't explain passages from literature. Such questions are even off-topic on [lierature.se] and [writers.se].

Comment: It's unclear.  Several possible interpretations.

Answer (score 1):

> **Terry**: Yes. I believe *that* [i.e., what you just said, Ron--I believe that my life is important without relying on God or religion].